# Is there a way to access Java constants in an hibernate entity xml mapping?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have an xml mapping and I would like to use java constants (Strings) for names of attributes or table. Is there a way to do so?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">
    <entity class="Trip" name="Trip">
        <table name="Trip"/>
        <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="dst.ass1.jpa.listener.TripListener">
            </entity-listener>
        </entity-listeners>
    <attributes>
```

...

Comment: You can't use Java constants in an XML file. But why do you need it? Maybe if you explain your problem in more detail people can help you achieve your goal in a different way.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use annotations?

Comment: Ah thank you. I wasn't aware whether you could do that. That's why I am asking. It's a university assignment, therefore I have to do it in form of an XML.